# Pandas Dataframe conversion to JSON

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a `Pandas` `Dataframe` or two rows with data that I'd like to pass as a `JSON` array.

The `JSON` needs to be formatted as follow:

```
[{
    "Date": "2017-02-03",
    "Text": "Sample Text1"
},
{
    "Date": "2015-02-04",
    "Text": "Sample Text2"
}]
```

I tried using `df.to_json(orient='index')`, but the output is not quite right as it seems to be using the `index` values as `keys`

```
{"0":{"Date":"2017-02-03","Text""Sample Text1"},"1":{"Date":"2017-02-04","Text""Sample Text2"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an array of dictionaries, you can use `orient='records'`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'Date': ['2017-02-03', '2015-02-04'],
...     'Text': ['Sample Text 1', 'Sample Text 2']
... })
>>> df.to_json(orient='records')
'[{"Date":"2017-02-03","Text":"Sample Text 1"},{"Date":"2015-02-04","Text":"Sample Text 2"}]'
```